# Date string has all zeros, unable to convert into NSDate object using NSDateFormatter

Tags: nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am receiving all zeros as a date string for some objects from the server (0000-00-00 00:00:00), So as I am trying to convert this string to `NSDate` object using `NSDateFormatter`, **it is returning nil**.
`dateformat style: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`"

Could anybody help me on how to get this done?

Comment: What date should that string be converted to?

Comment: I Just need that string to convert as a NSDate Object, right now, If I received all zeros, I am hardcoding the string to 1970-01-01 00:00:00